# Java - Spring - Hibernate extracting 1000 of objects from Database takes long time

Tags: java, database, spring, performance, hibernate

I have a **Postgres database** with 17 tables create by Hibernate with the **@Entity** annotation and iam running **CrudRepository** with the **findAll** method for extracting objects from the database

Everything works fine until I try to retrieve 1000 + objects from the database which takes 27 seconds. Retrieving 600 objects takes around 10 seconds.

The time is increasing exponentially and I am wondering if there is a solution to this, I know that if I try to join tables it would speed up the process but joining tables on 17 tables is a lot of work. Are there other extracting methods that are faster on retrieving objects besides the one that I am using?

**This is how I retrieve objects:**

```
public List<Document> getAllDatabaseDocuments() {
    List<Document> listOfDocs = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfDocs.addAll((List<Document>) sdr.findAll());
    return listOfDocs;
}
```

Comment: how exactly do you retrieve the data? hard to tell if there are better ways without knowing the code to retrieve the data as well as the database structure

Comment: Also entity classes are a must for this kind of question

Comment: CrudRepository is an interface that has a method called "findAll" I just call that method and cast the result to the class of the object

Comment: Send some code.The time will increase as data grows. Why do you have to pull all data at once? Depending on your use case, the solution will vary

Comment: The project has like 20+ classes....Would take to much time to show them all. But the way how is described in my post and that's all the code for retrieving the objects, it's only 3 lines.

Comment: you are doing something horribly wrong. 10 seconds should be the time for at least 100k records if not more. break down the example down to 1 entity and show us how you retrieve only that entity

Comment: Are the entities hierarchical? How many queries do you see when retrieving the data? N+1?

Comment: eg: check the oneToMany fetch type

Comment: @hovanessyan I don't check how many queries I see, how do I check that?

Comment: in application properties -spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

Comment: I updated my post with the code of how I retrieve objects

Comment: You need to post the Document entity

Comment: and the code for `sdr.findAll()`

Comment: Post the query which is getting executed to fetch the objects. This might be N+1 select problem

Comment: @XtremeBaumer there is no code behind findAll() except for the one that i put in my post. I just call the findAll method from the CrudRepository interface

Comment: if it is an interface, then it has some implementation. show that to us. also post your `Document` class

Answer (score 0):

All JPA providers have `QueryHints` to do certain query optimization. It provides you with the ability to fetch all associations in a single query or using joins. For example, In EclipseLink, you can use `QueryHints.BATCH` to fetch all `one to many` or `many to many` associations in a single query.

Instead of using `findAll()`, create your own query in your entity and provide the appropriate query hint specific to hibernate. `join-fetch` in your case will take a lot of time because you have a lot of related entities. Try to use `batch-fetch` as it will reduce the number of queries and effectively speeds up the fetching.

You can learn more about hibernate specific fetching strategies [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html)